# ajax.beginform to call many actions

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone explain to me how (if possible) to call multiple actions using one Ajax.BeginForm in an MVC4 view? Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have a form in my view that provides two parameters to the Controller. In this view I also have four partial views to update when the form is submitted. Each action returns a partial view that updates the 4 sections of the page.

From what I understand, each Ajax.BeginForm can call one and only one action on the Controller. What is the best way to update four partial views on a page at the click of a button in the form?

Here is what my view looks like.

```
  <div id="dayTab" data-metro-container="dashboardForm">
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Products", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="ProductsDiv", OnComplete = "processDay" }))
  {
    <table>
        <tr>@Html.ValidationSummary()</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Strings.LabelDashboardDate :
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateRangeFilter)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRangeCriteria, new { @class = "dateRangeClass" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="btnApply" type="submit" name="btnApply" value="@Strings.LabelApply" title="@Strings.TooltipDashboardApply" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="customNoWrap" data-metro-spinner="spinner" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="@ConfigurationCache.Settings.CSSPath/Content/themes/metro/Images/loading.gif")" alt="" class="metroCenterTag"/>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  }

<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="ProductsDiv">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Products"); }
    </div>
    <div id="QuantitiesDiv" style="height: 200px;">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Quantities"); }
    </div>            
</div>

<div style="float: left;">
    <div id="PurchaseOrdersDiv" style="margin-left: 10px;">
      @{ Html.RenderAction("PurchaseOrders"); }
    </div>
    <div id="BoxesDiv" style="margin-left: 10px;">
      @{ Html.RenderAction("Boxes"); }
    </div>
    <div id="PalletsDiv" style="margin-left: 10px;">
      @{ Html.RenderAction("Pallets"); }
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

I actually have four tabs in a jQuery tab and each tab has the same structure, same partial views. The form has to be submitted and updates the 4 partial views in the current tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the only purpose of your ajax for is to set the filter criteria in the server, so the other 4 partial views can use them to render accordingly.

Why not just letting the action you are calling using Ajax return all the markup you need, and update a container with it? If you call the action using ajax, you can then render a partial view which would contain the 4 partial views you need here. That, IMHO is simpler and clearer.

Anyways, what you want can be done. If modifying your plumbing is not an option this is what you can do:

1) Specify a handler for success in your Ajax options:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                OnSuccess = "LoadPartialViews()"
            }
```

2) Decorate each of your partial containers with the url for each of them:

```
<div id="ProductsDiv" data-url="@Url.Action("Products")">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Products"); }
</div>

//and so on for the rest of the partials
```

3) OnSuccess LoadPartialViews() is called, which would look like:

```
var LoadPartialViews = function (){
    var productsUrl = $("#ProductsDiv").data("url");
    //this will load the partial view content on the div... 
    $("#ProductsDiv").load(productsUrl, function(){});
};
```

Again, I'm sure you would be better with a single action driving all this rendering. On the first load, you can always assume some defaults, and fire the action, so you get initial content.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your step #1 is similar to what I already have. However, I like your idea of associating each div to the appropriate action using the data-url attribute. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of telling you how to squeeze the logic in Ajax.BeginForm, I'd point you out to check http://knockoutjs.com/ which works quite nice with ASP.NET MVC. If you have some data that several page elements are dependant on, you will do job much more effectively with KnockoutJS as it allows your view elements to update when the underlying depending data is changing - and it does it automatically for you. There is awesome online tutorial that will take you 1-2 hours to do, and it is very detailed.